# Cannot find docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wanted to edit the docker compose file of a project. After using docker inspect I found this:
`com.docker.compose.project.config_files    /data/compose/15/docker-compose.yml`

But the directory /data/* does not exist and therefore I cannot find the compose file to edit. Where can I find the docker-compose.yml file?

I tried to access the /data directory but this doesn’t exist

Comment: How did you originally start the project?  Do you have its source code?

Comment: @DavidMaze I created it using portainer (over portainer agent). Iirc portainer agent used volumes in prior versions but now it doesn‘t use volumes anymore so I believe that the /data directory where the docker-compose.yml is included is in the old volume. But the volume doesn‘t exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by restoring the docker-compose.yml file from a previous Portainer backup and starting the stack via SSH and not in Portainer